# DataBindig returns wrong onFocusChangeListener to layout

Tags: java, android, data-binding, android-databinding

I have a login form validation mechanism. There are two TextInputEditTexts for email and password, both being attached to respective onFocusChangeListeners, DataBinding is used to set those, but DataBinding returns wrong listeners.

Here is the form:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout>
    <data>
        <variable
            name="loginViewModel"
            type="com.example.increaseyouriq.ui.forms.LoginFormViewModel" />
    </data>
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/ll_login"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    style="@style/parent.contentLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="26dp">

    <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
        style="@style/cardOutline"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="16dp">

            <TextView
                style="@style/viewParent.headerText"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/login_title" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                    style="@style/textInputStyle"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:hint="@string/enter_email"
                    error="@{loginViewModel.loginForm.emailError}"
                    app:errorEnabled="@{loginViewModel.loginForm.isEmailError()}"
                    app:endIconMode="clear_text">

                    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                        android:id="@+id/et_login_email"
                        style="@style/textInputEditext"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        onFocus="@{loginViewModel.onFocusEmailChangeListener}"
                        android:text="@={loginViewModel.loginFields.email}"
                        android:inputType="textNoSuggestions|textEmailAddress" />

                </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                    style="@style/textInputStyle"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="@string/enter_password"
                    error="@{loginViewModel.loginForm.passwordError}"
                    app:errorEnabled="@{loginViewModel.loginForm.isPasswordError()}"
                    app:endIconMode="password_toggle">

                    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                        style="@style/textInputEditext"
                        android:id="@+id/et_login_password"
                        onFocus="@{loginViewModel.onFocusPasswordChangeListener}"
                        android:text="@={loginViewModel.loginFields.password}"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:inputType="textPassword" />

                </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>

</LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

Here is my **LoginFormViewModel.java**:

```
public class LoginFormViewModel extends ViewModel {
    private static final String LOG_TAG = "LoginFormViewModel";

    private View.OnFocusChangeListener onFocusEmail;
    private View.OnFocusChangeListener onFocusPassword;


    public void init() {
        loginForm = new LoginForm();

        onFocusPassword = (v, hasFocus) -> {
            TextInputEditText et = (TextInputEditText) v;
            MyUtilsApp.showLog(LOG_TAG,
                    String.format("%s password listener attached to :%d", String.valueOf(et.getText()), et.getId()));

            if (et.getText().length() > 0 && !hasFocus) {
                loginForm.isPasswordValid(true);
            }
        };

        onFocusEmail = (v, hasFocus) -> {
            TextInputEditText et = (TextInputEditText) v;

            MyUtilsApp.showLog(LOG_TAG, "email listener attached");

            if (et.getText().length() > 0 && !hasFocus) {
                loginForm.isEmailValid(true);
            }
        };

    }



    public View.OnFocusChangeListener getOnFocusEmailChangeListener() {
        return onFocusEmail;
    }

    public View.OnFocusChangeListener getOnFocusPasswordChangeListener() {
        return onFocusPassword;
    }

    @BindingAdapter("onFocus")
    public static void bindFocusChange(TextInputEditText editText, View.OnFocusChangeListener onFocusChangeListener) {
        if (editText.getOnFocusChangeListener() == null) {
            editText.setOnFocusChangeListener(onFocusChangeListener);
        }
    }

}
```

Here is my **LoginActivity.java**:

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String LOG_TAG = "LoginActivity";
    ActivityLoginBinding binding;
    private LoginRegisterViewModel loginRegisterViewModel;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this,R.layout.activity_login);
        setupBindings(savedInstanceState);

    }


    private void setupBindings(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        LoginFormViewModel loginFormViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(LoginFormViewModel.class);

        if(savedInstanceState==null)
            loginFormViewModel.init();

        binding.setLoginViewModel(loginFormViewModel);
        binding.setLifecycleOwner(this);

        loginFormViewModel.getLoginFields().observe(this, loginFields -> {
            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this,
                    "Email " + loginFields.getEmail() + ", Password " + loginFields.getPassword(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        });

        binding.inLayoutLogin.btnLoginLogin.setOnClickListener(view -> {
            binding.executePendingBindings();
            loginFormViewModel.getLoginForm().onClick();

        });
    }

}
```

As evident, I have set both listeners to be of onFocusEmail kind, just because onFocusPassword is being attached to both TextInputEditTexts during runtime.
Here are logs:

```
com.example.increaseyouriq E/LoginFormViewModel:  password listener attached to :2131296499
com.example.increaseyouriq E/LoginFormViewModel: ttf password listener attached to :2131296499
```

onFocusEmail is nowhere to be seen, it has been attached during runtime.
for more details on code see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67145503/data-binding-view-not-updating-the-variabe-in-inner-classes-of-observable)

Answer (score 0):

I did some experiments on your code and I believe I found out the underlying reason.

**Problem:**

Neither of your listeners are attached to your email field (TextInputEditText "et_login_email").

**Reason:**

The reason is that you have a null check here;

```
@BindingAdapter("onFocus")
public static void bindFocusChange(TextInputEditText editText, View.OnFocusChangeListener onFocusChangeListener) {
    if (editText.getOnFocusChangeListener() == null) {
        editText.setOnFocusChangeListener(onFocusChangeListener);
    }
}
```

And your email field has an onFocusChangeListener already which is set by ["app:endIconMode="clear_text""](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/lib/java/com/google/android/material/textfield/ClearTextEndIconDelegate.java) attribute.

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    ...
    android:hint="@string/enter_email"
    ..."
    app:endIconMode="clear_text">
```

You cannot set a listener to the email field because its listener is not null from the begining and the current method (bindFocusChange()) only sets it when it is null.

**Solution 1:**

Remove your null check when setting the onFocusChangeListeners.

**Solution 2:**

Utilize data binding library's [automatic method selection](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/binding-adapters#automatic-setting) with less code.

Change your custom attribute's name "onFocus" to "onFocusChangeListener". As the TextInputEditText fields have a matching setter method (setOnFocusChangeListener) for this name, the library can handle this automatically and you can remove your "*bindFocusChange(...)*" method completely: